# Embedded video (from the internet) player flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm making a movie player app (for my school project) and i found a pretty nice API contains about 800 movies. The problem is the link to these video is embedded video

Example: https://www.youtube.com/embed/PSHFCBVD8Po,

https://ok.ru/videoembed/2391306930885,

https://em.iq.com/player.html?id=1fukdw5shuk&lid=23&lang=vi_vn&mod=vn&ad_config=1

https://streamtape.com/e/Dk9L6Qo9wxUk2eg/,

How can i play these video on my app?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

if you want to play video from youtube there is a plugin that can help you to play youtube embedded video

here is the plugin link
[enter link description here](https://pub.dev/packages/youtube_player_flutter)

if you want to play all embedded video than you need to implement webview video player to play embedded videos in your flutter app

here is the medium blog that can help you [enter link description here](https://najyfannoun.medium.com/how-to-play-embedded-videos-in-mobile-applications-using-flutter-51accad57721)

Comment: oh ty! i think this is enough for me